# Is there a way to search comments/answers by user related to another user?

Tags: support

I remember Adrian had a useful comment on one of my posts a few weeks back. The problem is we've both made comments and answers since then that it's pushed down somewhere in a sea of posts.

Is there a way to search through questions I've asked to get results of a specific user's comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, however if you favorite it you can do a search like this:

```
user:887 infavorites:mine
```

It will search in your favorites for any results authored by the user Id 887 (KeithC) in this case. You can find the Id by clicking on a users name and looking in the URL